# How to get data attributes in Bootstrap 4 popover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, popover

I have this situation.

open popover button:

```
<a href="#" id="popover" data-plan-type="2" data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom">
<i class="fal fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
```

popover settings:

```
let orderPlanPopoverSettings = {

        html: true,
        selector: 'a#order-plan-popover',
        content: function () {

            return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();

        }

    };
```

popover:

```
$('body').popover(orderPlanPopoverSettings).on('show.bs.popover', function(e) {

   //GET POPOVER BUTTON data-plan-type

});
```

I need get in *show.bs.popover* button data attributes *data-plan-type*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event target (`e.target`), is the element that triggered the popover. Then use jQuery `data()` for the "plan-type" value..

```
$('body').popover(orderPlanPopoverSettings).on('show.bs.popover', function(e) {

   //GET POPOVER BUTTON data-plan-type
   var planType = $(e.target).data("plan-type");
   console.log(planType);

});
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/I7Zh7ohhJw